# Wait for a thread inside a C++ static object

Tags: dll, c++14, clr, unmanaged, managed

I have a static object that needs to initialize an imaging API. The allocated resources of this imaging API need to be released by the same thread.
So I'm starting a thread in my static object that initializes everything and then waits for a counter to reach zero. When this happens the thread cleans all up and finishes.

This is an unmanaged class inside a managed library, so I can't use System::Threading::Thread (needs a managed static member function) or std::thread (compiler error, not supported with /clr).

So I have to start my thread like:

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&Initialize, this, 0, 0);
```

All works fine, the init is done and the API functions work. But when I close the application I see that the usage counter of my static object reaches zero but the clean up function is never called by the thread, as if the thread was killed. Is there a way to make sure the thread will continue to exist and execute until its end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After turning this around in all possible ways and adding events etc I guess this is not possible so I'll have to change the structure of my code and encapsulate the non managed class inside a managed class, and add the thread to the managed class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could proceed in one of two ways:

- Wrap the resources in [RAII-style](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) classes, and refactor to have the objects' lifetimes be on the stack of your created thread, ensuring their destructors get called when the thread loop exits without having to call any additional cleanup. If there is no issue with the thread returning correctly when your counter reaches 0, this should be the simplest and cleanest way of addressing this.
- I'm thinking you could intercept the `WM_CLOSE` message using [window procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-procedures?redirectedfrom=MSDN), process necessary cleanup and then pass the message on, effectively "stalling" it until you are ready to close. Note that even though you are in a DLL you can still set up a window procedure and message pump system, you don't need a GUI to do that. I am however not 100% sure on whether you'll receive the `WM_CLOSE` message that concerns the application that "owns" your DLL, it's not something I've tried out yet.

You will have to implement some form of messaging through [events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjectsex) within your thread's loop however, as the WindowProc will be called on a different thread, so you know when to call the cleanup procedure.

I also am not very familiar with CLR, so there might be a simpler way of interacting with those APIs than with raw C++ calls and handles.

Comment: If I put a break point in the object that decreases the counter, it stops there. If I put a break point in the cleanup function it never stops there.

Comment: Alright, and does the thread return correctly once the counter hits 0, even if it never goes into the cleanup function? I edited my remarks out of the answer since apparently I can comment here ^^

Comment: I do a Debug::Print of its handle when it is created, no trace of it in the list of terminated threads at the end (the auto generated exited threads list with exit code)

Comment: Ah, seeing your answer I guess it's maybe a weird interaction from running an unmanaged thread in managed code? Sorry I couldn't help, good luck!

Comment: Yes in fact using CreateThread() it creates a Win32 thread I guess, that is not well managed by the rest of the application. I also made some testing with another managed class and a System::Threading::Thread and its finalizer (managed destructor) is not called while the thread still exists! Its a completely different behavior.

Comment: Yeah, Win32 threads need to be manually closed, ideally from within by returning through signalling if they're in a loop (if you force close them destructors won't get called), and join mechanics - iirc even CloseHandle only kills the handle to the thread, not the thread itself.